# how to view hardcoded data in highchart drilldown to pie chart laravel php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts, highcharts

hey guys how can i show the hardcoded data using highchart? currently i have a bar chart and drilldown to pie chart, so the bar chart is working fine with hardcoded and dynamically but the pie chart is not showing me the hardcoded data instead its saying its 'undefined' so how can i solve this? my code is as below:

```html
<script>

  $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['Total', 'Match'],
            name = 'total vs match',
            data = [{
                    y: {!! $countTotalRecord['total'] !!},
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: '',
                        categories: ['Low Confidence', 'No Answer', 'Missing Intent', 'Webhook Fail'],
                        data: [{!! $countTotalRecord['low confidence'] !!}, {!! $countTotalRecord['no answer'] !!}, {!! $countTotalRecord['missing intent'] !!}, {!! $countTotalRecord['webhook fail'] !!}],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: {!! $countTotalRecord['match'] !!},
                    color: colors[1]
                }];
    
        function setChart(options) {
            chart.series[0].remove(false);
            chart.addSeries({
                type: options.type,
                name: options.name,
                data: options.data,
                color: options.color || 'white'
            }, false);
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(options.categories, false);
            chart.redraw();
        }
    
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                var options;
                                if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                    options = {
                                        'name': drilldown.name,
                                        'categories': drilldown.categories,
                                        'data': drilldown.data,
                                        'color': drilldown.color,
                                        'type': 'pie'
                                    };
                                } else { // restore
                                    options = {
                                        'name': name,
                                        'categories': categories,
                                        'data': data,
                                        'type': 'column'
                                    };
                                }
                                setChart(options);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var point = this.point,
                        s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'</b><br/>'+ this.percentage +'%<br/>';
                    if (point.drilldown) {
                        s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' data';
                    } else {
                        s += 'Click to return';
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                name: name,
                data: data,
                color: 'white'
            }],
            credits:{
              enabled:false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });
    });
    
});


</script>
```

Comment: Hi, check http://jsfiddle.net/cn9q8nuo/ for IE and chrome pie drill down static data

Comment: In which place do you see `undefinded`? In **tooltip**?